# "authorization request has expired" error on IOS mobile chrome

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

When my plugin makes an authorization request using mobile chrome on IoS, the banno server is rendering the following error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "authorization request has expired",
  "request_id": "69a2e6d2329e0c1e45c6b06549930d7c"
}
```

The authorization request that my plugin is using works just fine on safari on IoS, mobile chrome on android, and all other desktop web browsers on other operating systems.

This problem is unique to mobile chrome on IoS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more testing we were able to confirm this bug on an old version of chrome on IOS, verion 92.0.4515.90. Newer versions of chrome were unable to reproduce. It seems likely this was a bug in an older chrome version

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your plugin isn't properly handling sessions.

Per [Designing and Developing Plugins](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#authentication):

> The Authentication Framework provides authenticated identity information about the user, but is specifically not a session manager. You will have to manage your own user session within your plugin.

Comment: This happens on the authorization redirect, before any session is created or any user is identified. There is no session involved when this error occurs.

Comment: To clarify, this happens on the [authorization request](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/authorization/the-authorization-request/).

An authorization request is the very first request in the oauth flow and it looks something like this:

`https://customer.org/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/auth?claims=foo&response_type=code&state=foobar`

Comment: It would be odd for Chrome on iOS to be _specifically_ doing something odd with the caching of cookies, etc but it's certainly _possible_. I'd recommend clearing the browser cache, rebooting the device, and perhaps trying with a completely fresh user.

Comment: After more testing we were able to confirm this bug on an old version of chrome on IOS 92.0.4515.90. Newer versions of chrome were unable to reproduce. It seems likely this was a bug in an older chrome version.

Comment: Oof. Thanks for following up.